# Iterating over different hashes with one method in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I've been working on a lab that wants you to build a method key_for_min_value that accepts an argument of a hash. The method should iterate over the hash and return the key that points to the smallest value of the set. If the method is called and passed an argument of an empty hash, it should return nil.

My issue is here is that two different hashes have to be iterated over for the test to pass. I'm a bit confused on how to create the logic in my method to validate both pieces contained in the method. I've thought about adding more logic to my loop, but I'm not sure if that's the cleanest way to write this. Any insight would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
hash = {:blake => 500, :ashley => 2, :adam => 1}
hash = {:blake => 10, :ashley => 50, :adam => 17}

def key_for_min_value(name_hash)
  empty_hash = nil
   name_hash.collect do |name, value|
     if value <= 1
       return name
   end
  end
  empty_hash
end
```

Comment: Your function is not finding the smallest value; it is finding the value that is less or equal to `1`. You don't need _more_ logic, you need _different_ logic. `#collect` is a wrong tool for the job. Look at `#min_by` instead, or if you think that's cheating, then `#inject`.

Comment: So the lab disallows me from using min_by and sort_by.

Comment: If I use inject vs collect, I'm pretty sure I wouldn't need to have a loop there correct? Or at least not one that has arithmetic

Comment: both `#collect` and `#inject` are loops; they just do different things.

Comment: Sure, though it's a bit easier with `#inject`. You have to track where the lowest element you found so far is, and compare each element against that (i.e. not hardcode `<= 1`, not `== 0`, or similar.

Comment: "[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/128421)" might be useful.

Comment: My apologies. My goal isn't to have the code given to me; I genuinely want to understand this!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
def key_for_min_value(name_hash)

    name_hash.reduce([nil, nil]){
        |acc, (key, value)|
        if acc[0].nil?
            [key, value]
        elsif acc[1] > value
            [key, value]
        else
            acc
        end
    }.first

end
```

with input:

```
hash1 = {:blake => 500, :ashley => 2, :adam => 1}
hash2 = {:blake => 10, :ashley => 50, :adam => 17}
hash3 = {}
```

will produce:

```
:adam
:blake
nil
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def key_for_min_value(hash)
  values = hash.values
  hash.keys[values.index(values.min).to_i]
end
```

`values` is being used twice in the last statement that is why I assigned it. otherwise, I would just call `hash.values` and the method would only be a 1 line method.

It'll also return `nil` if the hash is empty

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing some videos and the documentation, I eventually came up with this:

```
def key_for_min_value(name_hash)
 smallest_value = 0
 empty_hash = nil
 name_hash.each do |name, value|
  if smallest_value == 0 || value < smallest_value
    smallest_value = value
    empty_hash = name
  end
 end
 empty_hash
end
```

My concern is that once I get to the block, I started to retreat into creating something that feels a bit dry. I ran this, and I was able to pass the tests. I'm not sure if this would be considered clean, though. I wasn't able to use methods like sort_by or min_by, so I had to get creative with my loop. Any feedback would be great on how I could turn this into something more abstract.

Comment: Default of 0 for `smallest_value` does not look right. It should start with value of the first element (ideally).

Comment: Also `empty_hash` is not at all like its name :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: It may not be too intuitive for a beginner how to start with the second value. `nil` with an appropriate guard is usually okay. But in case of looking for a numerical minimum, the magic starting value `-Float::INFINITY` is very nice (as you need no extra logic).

Answer (score 0):

You method will look like,

```
def key_for_min_value(hash)
  hash.inject { |m,a| m[1] > a[1] ? a : m }[0] unless hash.empty?
end
```

Comment: And while we're at it, drop the default memo value parameter to inject, it's redundant here :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thanks, I understood but did not know before that for array/hash, accumulator default value is first element.

Comment: "for array/hash" - not only for array/hash, this applies to everything you can call `inject` on.